# How to create a dataframe with the column included in groupby clause?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame. It has 3 columns A, Amount. I have done a group by using 'A'. Now I want to insert these values into a new data frame how can I achieve this?

```
top_plt=pd.DataFrame(top_plt.groupby('A')['Amount'].sum())
```

The resulting dataframe contains only the Amount column but the groupby 'A' column is missing.
Example:
[image: START]
Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

`DataFrame` constructor is not necessary, better is add `as_index=False` to `groupby`:

```
top_plt= top_plt.groupby('A', as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
```

Or add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
top_plt= top_plt.groupby('A')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```